# I am getting an "incompatible types" error right here and I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

Please help to find where my code is "incompatible type"....I've looked and looked and looked and can't find it anywhere.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Years
{
    private int centuries, decades;

    public Years(int years)
    {
        centuries = years / 100;
        years -= 25 * years;
        decades = years / 10;
        years -= 10 * years;
    }
    public int getCenturies()
    {
        return centuries;
    }
    public int getDecades()
    {
        return decades;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int years;

        if(args.length >= 1)
        {
            years = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the amount in years: ");
            years = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.close();
        }

        Years y = new Years(years);
        System.out.println(years = "y =" + 
        y.getCenturies() + "c +" + y.getDecades() + "d"); // I am getting the error right here.
        }
}
```

Comment: You should put where you are getting the error, not just the error itself

Comment: I used a comment to show where the error is...the error is towards the bottom of the program.

Comment: if you look at System.out.println(`years = "y ="` + , there is a concatenating problem there

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(
    years = "y =" + y.getCenturies() + "c +" + y.getDecades() + "d"
);
//  ^^^^^^^
```

The problem is `years =`. The compiler is not really sure what to do with this. The result of the right hand side of the `=` is a String because you are performing String concatenation.

So the compiler thinks you are doing this:

```
years = ("y =" + y.getCenturies() + "c +" + y.getDecades() + "d")
```

`years` is an int so this is not a valid expression.

You probably just meant this:

```
System.out.println(
    "y = " + y.getCenturies() + "c + " + y.getDecades() + "d"
);
```

Or possibly to concatenate `years` somewhere in there:

```
System.out.println(
    years + "y = " +
    y.getCenturies() + "c + " + y.getDecades() + "d"
);
```